# How to rename multiple columns at once in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with multiple years as variable headings with the format:
Y_1998, Y_1999, etc up to 2018. Is there any way that I can rename all of these columns in a single line of code, instead of using the rename function for each variable?

Comment: You can assign a vector to the names of your ```data.frame()```

Comment: `names(data) <- sub("Y_", "Year_", names(data))`  Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page on providing a complete reproducible example.

Answer (score 7):

If your `dplyr` version is `>=1.0.0` then you can use `rename_with()` and one of the select helpers (e.g. `starts_with()`) to match a pattern of column name.

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(var1 = "a",
       Y_1999 = 1, Y_2000 = 0, Y_2001 = 1, Y_2002 = 0,
       some_other_var = "b") %>% 
  rename_with(.fn = ~ str_replace(.x, "Y_", "Year_"),
              .cols = starts_with("Y_"))
```